# How do I log in the console the name of the file you are viewing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to log in the console the name of the page.

Say you were on index.html, then in the console it would say 'index.html'

Answer (score 0):

Get the pathname with `window.location.pathname`, then find the current page by splitting it by `/`s and getting the last item.

```js
console.log("Full URL: " + location);
console.log("Current Page: " + window.location.pathname.split("/").pop());
```

Comment: would i be able to display this with innerHTML?

Comment: @bk.wtf Of course. How do you want to do it?

Answer (score 0):

One quick google search has given me this answer:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```